# can only be updated by trigger in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
create table users(
    userid bigint primary key,
    email text not null,
    created_by text not null default  current_user,
    created_on timestamptz not null default  now(),
    updated_on timestamptz,
    updated_by text
);
```

I can make trigger to update the last 4 columns. I can also create view.

```
create view users_template AS select userid, email from users;
GRANT ALL ON users_template TO public;
```

Since column level security is a bad idea. [Postgres Column Level Security](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239577/postgres-column-level-security)
in view there is also an `security_barrier` but I don't know how to use.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604447/create-hidden-column-in-postgresql#:~:text=No%2C%20there%20is%20no%20supported,defined%20columns%20from%20the%20*%20wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604447/create-hidden-column-in-postgresql#:%7E:text=No%2C%20there%20is%20no%20supported,defined%20columns%20from%20the%20*%20wildcard).

So is possible to grant select only on users. grant all to users_template.
The end goal is `create_by, created_on, updated_on, updated_by` should be updated by trigger only.

I feel like is possible:

> Note that the user performing the insert, update or delete on the view
> must have the corresponding insert, update or delete privilege on the
> view. In addition the view's owner must have the relevant privileges
> on the underlying base relations, but the **user performing the update
> does not need any permissions on the underlying base relations** (see
> Section 41.5).
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=708e1b8072875ea241a5d49f1f367e6d)

Comment: Sure, that is easily possible. What problems do you encounter?

Comment: I added the db fiddle link, now the trigger works on `updated_by`,`updated_on`, but we can still change the value of `created_on` ,`cerated_by`. then how to make `created_on` ,`cerated_by`. the value first time insert is the default insert value, after that these two columns value never change.  @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: The question should be understandable even without the dbfiddle (which is a good addition).

Answer (score 1):

insert issue:
except the table owner, other's can only `insert` via `users_template` view. So except userid, email column, all other columns will be trigger generated.

```
create view users_template AS select userid, email from users;
GRANT ALL ON users_template TO public;
grant select, update on users to public;
```

---

update issue:
-- some columns(updated_on, updated_by) value will be changed by trigger.
-- some columns(created_by, created_on) value will remain the same.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_users_column()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
   NEW.updated_on = now();
   NEW.updated_by = current_user;
   NEW.created_by = OLD.created_by;
   NEW.created_on = OLD.created_on;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_users_column BEFORE UPDATE
ON users FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_users_column();
```